# How to use "content entity" type in a View?

Tags: views, entities

I have used the "content entity example" coming from the [example project](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples).

This example module/:

- defines a "Contact" entity; it can have extra fields, displays can be configured (web/admin/structure/content_entity_example_contact_settings),
- gives the user the form to add content (contact info) to it. (/web/content_entity_example_contact/add)
- shows a list of the contacts (/web/content_entity_example_contact/list)

I want to make my list as a View, but this content entity type "Contact" is not there to select it. (I see only the node content types, users, taxonomy etcI

How can I use this content in a View ? What do I have to do to make this content available in the Views UI ? Where can I find the content entity types to create a view ? Or how can I add those ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a views_data handler to the entity type. Either the core standard `EntityViewsData`

*content_entity_example/src/Entity/Contact.php*

```
  *   handlers = {
  *     "views_data" = "Drupal\views\EntityViewsData",
```

or a custom handler:

*content_entity_example/src/Entity/Contact.php*

```
  *   handlers = {
  *     "views_data" = "Drupal\content_entity_example\Entity\ContactViewsData",
```

*content_entity_example/src/Entity/ContactViewsData.php*

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\content_entity_example\Entity;

use Drupal\views\EntityViewsData;

/**
 * Makes the content_entity_example entity available to Views
 *
 * @ingroup content_entity_example
 */
class ContactViewsData extends EntityViewsData {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getViewsData() {
    $data = parent::getViewsData();

    // $data from the parent is enough to make it work but modify as required.

    // Give it a more description name in the dropdown when creating a new view.
    $data['contact']['table']['base']['title'] = $this->t('Content Entity Example Contact');

    // Make the Name field appear to Views as Last Name
    $data['contact']['name']['title'] = $this->t('Last Name');

    return $data;
  }

}
```

To apply this code to the example module use the patch from this issue https://www.drupal.org/project/examples/issues/2725833

Comment: I am now having trouble using a relationship and contextual filters (to show all contacts on a user/%/tab ) but I think that is another question. (using the core standard handler)